# React Hook in Event Handler is not a function Error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm using react-hook-form (RHF) for creating a form. "onSubmit" I want to run the "searchOrig" function, which sets the state "segment" via "setSegment". (So basically I want to set a state with react useState in an event handler which is used by RHF)

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"

    const SegmentForm = () => {
      const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm()
      const { segment, setSegment } = useState(null)
      const searchOrig = data => {
        console.log(data)
        setSegment("ORIGIN")
      }

      return (
        <>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(searchOrig)}>
            <input name="origin" placeholder="Origin" ref={register} />
            <input type="submit" />
          </form>
        </>
      )
    }

    export default SegmentForm
```

Unfortunately I get this error when submitting:

[image]

Does anyone know why this error occurs and how to fix it? Or another way to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your syntax looks incorrect for `useState` hooks. they export an array. Can you try `const [segment, setSegment] = useState(null)`?

Comment: That's it... Thank you so much! I guess I was looking at the line above while typing...